# Compose key doesn't work in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, input-method, compose-key

I set Compose Key as <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> in Tweaks. It was fine until 17.10, but since I upgraded Ubuntu into 18.04, Compose Key doesn't work.

I've installed `uim` and set it as default input method, and made `~/.XCompose` as follows:

```
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/ko_KR.UTF-8/Compose"
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's because I had Korean as only input source; It doesn't have any Compose Key sequences. I accidentally removed English input source in the process.

Re-adding the English input source solved the problem.

***EDIT:*** Also restarting the system was required to `uim` to work. So I can leave Korean as only input source. **(Not quite; see below.)**

**EDIT 2:** The action in **EDIT** makes Hangul unavailable. This issue will be discussed later.

**EDIT 3:** It turns out that in `uim`, the input method for Korean is called `Byeoru`. I set the proper hotkey for Han/Eng switching, and everything's okay now.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem, Compose Key does not work, I have only 1 input source, English (US, intl, with dead key), Language = English (US), Formats = US, so with this configuration, Compose Key should work, but it doesn't. Maybe I'm not doing it right, this is what I did: after I set the compose key to PrtSc in Tweak, then I pressed PrtSc, then c, then ', it showed just c, so what am I missing?

Comment: @Michael You should ask a separate question for that.